# Avoid onbeforeunload in location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below which asks for confirmation when a user tries to reload the page. It works fine

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    return confirm('Confirm refresh');
};
```

In another part of the code, I am redirecting it to the page using `window.location.href` It returns a popup whether you want to leave the page. How can I avoid this popup when using `window.location.href`?

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.split('#')[0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set a variable to skip this behaviour :

```
let skipUnloadConfirm = false;

window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
   if(!skipUnloadConfirm) {
      return confirm('Confirm refresh');
   }
};
```

And then change value before setting href (function would replace direct `window.location.href` assignement and could be reused)

```
function redirect(url) {
  skipUnloadConfirm = true;
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

Or, you can override `window.onbeforeunload` before calling `redirect`